# Google Chrome: Search API?

Tags: google-chrome, search, web, opensearch

I'm looking for a way to expose Google-Search functionality on my site so that chrome users can use context-sensitive searching (e.g:)

[Chrome Search http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7762/chromesearch.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7762/chromesearch.png)

I know YouTube is owned by Google, but I couldn't remember which 3rd party sites I had seen this feature work on before. Anyway, I couldn't find any reference to this in google-labs or on code.google.com, so I've turned to you SO.

If anyone has any insight in how to expose this, or a reference doc, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please note that I am basing my answer off of the context of your question, as at my work I cannot see the image. If my answer is not what you are looking for, please let me know.

I'm not sure if this exactly how Google Chrome does this, but Chrome supports it, and I found this by looking at the source code for this Stack Overflow page.

http://www.opensearch.org

This is an XML specification for providing custom searching. It is currently supported by Chrome, FF, and IE7.

If you want to look at an example page, this is the link to the Stack Overflow specification:

https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml

Comment: Glad I could be of help then!

Comment: Actually the link itself is broken